# Lifetime derived from a measured spectrum when initial and final state have a finite lifetime

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, half-life

Can we infer the lifetime of states from a simple absorption or emission spectrum if both states involved in the transition have finite lifetimes? For example excited state absorption. It seems that this would only be possible if the transition involves a state with an assumed infinite lifetime, typically the ground state. Then the FWHM of a Lorentzian shaped peak, due to natural line broadening, allows us to determine the life time of the second state involved.

But how would one determine the lifetime of a state that is not directly coupled to a state with infinite life time? Is the spectral line shape then given by a convolution of two different Lorentzians?